# Updating user info by using an user id with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to update existing user information in my database but no matter what I try it won't execute.

**Code :**

```
public function updateUser()
{
    $this->userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    var_dump($this->userId);
    include "DBConnect.php";
    $updateUser = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET 
    `user_username`=:user_name,`user_password`=:user_password,
    `user_firstname`=:user_firstname,`user_middlename`=:user_middlename,
    `user_lastname`=:user_lastname,`user_country`=user_country,
    `user_city`=:user_city,`user_street`=:user_street,
    `user_housenumber`=:user_housenumber,`user_postalcode`=:user_postalcode
    ,`user_email`=:user_email,`user_phone`=:user_phone 
    WHERE `user_id` =:user_id");
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_name', $this->userName);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_password', $this->userPassword);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_firstname', $this->userFirstName);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_middlename', $this->userMiddleName);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_lastname', $this->userLastName);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_country', $this->userCountry);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_city', $this->userCity);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_street', $this->userStreet);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_housenumber', $this->userHouseNumber);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_postalcode', $this->userPostalCode);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_email', $this->userEmail);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_phone', $this->userPhone);

    var_dump($this->userId);
    var_dump($this->userName);
    var_dump($this->userPassword);
    var_dump($this->userFirstName);
    var_dump($this->userMiddleName);
    var_dump($this->userLastName);
    var_dump($this->userCountry);
    var_dump($this->userCity);
    var_dump($this->userStreet);
    var_dump($this->userHouseNumber);
    var_dump($this->userPostalCode);
    var_dump($this->userEmail);
    var_dump($this->userPhone);

    $updateUser->execute();
}
```

**full error :**

```
string(1) "9" string(1) "9" string(4) "test" string(4) "test" string(4) "test" string(4) "test" string(4) "test" string(4) "test" string(4) "test" string(4) "test" string(2) "21" string(4) "test" string(4) "test" string(8) "12345678" 
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/webshop/classes/User.php:279 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/webshop/classes/User.php(279): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/webshop/adminpanel/userdashboard.php(23): User->updateUser() #2 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/webshop/classes/User.php on line 279
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear.. the number of PDO name variables in the query is not the same as you binding with `bindParam()`

Comment: indeed @Pupil this edit will directly show the topicstarter which one is missing.. Topicstarter SQL is meant to be readed, writing SQL as a "oneliner" without good formatting is 9 out of the 10 times trouble.

Comment: You are missing a `:` in ``user_country`=user_country,`

Answer (score 1):

I found it, you just missed a colon to add to `user_country`,Try this

```
{
    $this->userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    var_dump($this->userId);
    include "DBConnect.php";
    $updateUser = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET 
    `user_username`=:user_name,`user_password`=:user_password,
    `user_firstname`=:user_firstname,`user_middlename`=:user_middlename,
    `user_lastname`=:user_lastname,`user_country`=:user_country,
    `user_city`=:user_city,`user_street`=:user_street,
    `user_housenumber`=:user_housenumber,`user_postalcode`=:user_postalcode
    ,`user_email`=:user_email,`user_phone`=:user_phone 
    WHERE `user_id` =:user_id");
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_name', $this->userName);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_password', $this->userPassword);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_firstname', $this->userFirstName);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_middlename', $this->userMiddleName);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_lastname', $this->userLastName);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_country', $this->userCountry);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_city', $this->userCity);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_street', $this->userStreet);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_housenumber', $this->userHouseNumber);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_postalcode', $this->userPostalCode);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_email', $this->userEmail);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_phone', $this->userPhone);

    var_dump($this->userId);
    var_dump($this->userName);
    var_dump($this->userPassword);
    var_dump($this->userFirstName);
    var_dump($this->userMiddleName);
    var_dump($this->userLastName);
    var_dump($this->userCountry);
    var_dump($this->userCity);
    var_dump($this->userStreet);
    var_dump($this->userHouseNumber);
    var_dump($this->userPostalCode);
    var_dump($this->userEmail);
    var_dump($this->userPhone);

    $updateUser->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Find line:

```
user_lastname`=:user_lastname,`user_country`=user_country,
```

Replace by:

```
user_lastname`=:user_lastname,`user_country`=:user_country,
```

The missing semi colon before `user_country` is not binding it the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a typo error for user_name and user_country and session may not have been initialized. Finally you should check all variable for **spellings, typo, colon, comma errors** etc.

Below is just my findings from your code

**First You have**

```
`user_username`=:user_name,
```

instead of

```
`user_name`=:user_name,
```

**secondly**

you have(missing colon here)

```
 `user_country`=user_country,
```

instead of

```
 `user_country`=:user_country,
```

**thirdly**
 **user_id** is session based and I did not see where you initialized session in your code

```
session_start();
```

**Try this code**

```
public function updateUser()
{
session_start();
    $this->userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    var_dump($this->userId);
    include "DBConnect.php";

    $updateUser = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET 
    `user_name`=:user_name,
    `user_password`=:user_password,
    `user_firstname`=:user_firstname,
    `user_middlename`=:user_middlename,
    `user_lastname`=:user_lastname,
    `user_country`=:user_country,
    `user_city`=:user_city,
    `user_street`=:user_street,
    `user_housenumber`=:user_housenumber,
    `user_postalcode`=:user_postalcode
    ,`user_email`=:user_email,
    `user_phone`=:user_phone WHERE `user_id` =:user_id");

    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_name', $this->userName);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_password', $this->userPassword);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_firstname', $this->userFirstName);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_middlename', $this->userMiddleName);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_lastname', $this->userLastName);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_country', $this->userCountry);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_city', $this->userCity);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_street', $this->userStreet);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_housenumber', $this->userHouseNumber);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_postalcode', $this->userPostalCode);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_email', $this->userEmail);
    $updateUser->bindParam(':user_phone', $this->userPhone);

    var_dump($this->userId);
    var_dump($this->userName);
    var_dump($this->userPassword);
    var_dump($this->userFirstName);
    var_dump($this->userMiddleName);
    var_dump($this->userLastName);
    var_dump($this->userCountry);
    var_dump($this->userCity);
    var_dump($this->userStreet);
    var_dump($this->userHouseNumber);
    var_dump($this->userPostalCode);
    var_dump($this->userEmail);
    var_dump($this->userPhone);

    $updateUser->execute();
}
```

**Alternatively.**

Instead of using all this bind bind bind.......
you can just use **array method**. Let me know if there are more issues

```
public function updateUser()
{

//initialized session if you have not done so
session_start();
    $this->userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    var_dump($this->userId);
    include "DBConnect.php";


$updateUser = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET 
    `user_name`=:user_name,
    `user_password`=:user_password,
    `user_firstname`=:user_firstname,
    `user_middlename`=:user_middlename,
    `user_lastname`=:user_lastname,
    `user_country`=:user_country,
    `user_city`=:user_city,
    `user_street`=:user_street,
    `user_housenumber`=:user_housenumber,
    `user_postalcode`=:user_postalcode
    ,`user_email`=:user_email,
    `user_phone`=:user_phone WHERE `user_id` =:user_id");




$updateUser->execute(array(
 ':user_id' =>  $_SESSION['user_id'],
 ':user_name' => $this->userName,
 ':user_password'=> $this->userPassword,
 ':user_firstname'=> $this->userFirstName, 
 ':user_middlename'=> $this->userMiddleName, 
 ':user_lastname'=> $this->userLastName, 
 ':user_country'=> $this->userCountry, 
 ':user_city'=> $this->userCity, 
 ':user_street'=> $this->userStreet, 
 ':user_housenumber'=> $this->userHouseNumber, 
 ':user_postalcode'=> $this->userPostalCode,  
 ':user_email'=> $this->userEmail, 
 ':user_phone'=> $this->userPhone,

));


}
```

Comment: One **big** downside is that `execute()` can only bind as `PDO::PARAM_STR` so it's not ideal trusting on the database to correctly auto casting the data..